# AMP-HTML vs Firebase Hosting

Tags: amp-html, firebase-hosting

AMP-HTML is said to enable fastest page loading by combining coding best practices (resolution switching, no external stylesheets, minimal JavaScript, reflow avoidance) with global edge caching. The AMP library (`<script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>`) seems to tell Google's infrastructure to cache pages provided the page passes AMP validation.

Firebase Hosting, another Google property/project, [is said to deliver](https://firebase.google.com/products/hosting/)

> SSD-backed hosting, around the globe. No matter where a user is,
>   content is delivered fast. Files deployed to Firebase Hosting are cached on SSDs at CDN edge servers around the world.

So my question: Does AMP-HTML deliver any real caching advantage over Firebase Hosting?

Comment: You are comparing a HTML variation with a CDN hoster (btw. Firebase hosting uses Fastly). These things are not mutual exclusive. You should choose the fastest CDN you need/can afford. Additionally you can think about adding amp versions of your site.

Comment: @for3st thanks for the reply. ...Interesting re fastly. I did look at/evaluate AMP for a whole week, several hours/day + adding it to my homepage atleast. Ultimately, I decided against adopting it though. My decision boiled down to time/effort management, the KISS principle, and conviction to standards.